# What does a phrase "such is life in the tropics" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Recently I've read and article about one of Latin American countries. The author was explaining why the life there is easy in terms of natural resources: there is no winter, the people have fresh water and rich soil. And then he concluded that there is one English phrase that describes this situation:

> Such is life in the tropics.

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: It means exactly what each word means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, *Such is life in the tropics* speaks of the idiosyncrasies of living there. IOW, understanding the culture.

Comment: For the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned phrase would be:-

> The quality, situation or state of life in tropical forest regions.

Comment: Does it have a positive or negative meaning or it's similar to "life's like that" or "c'est la vie"?

Comment: @vero4ka It really depends on how the author phrased it, for example, if he kept talking about the harshness and difficulties of living in such areas, it is negative meaning or if he talk about how beautiful the nature is, how the trees breathe peace and serenity and stuff like that then it would be positive meaning.